# Flutter : Why Text Widget on Flutter automatically centered when placed before TextField Widget ? ( Inside Column Widget )

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So i tried to make my TextWidget aligned to left but when i put TextWidget above ( before ) TextFieldWidget it's automatically become centered following with the TextFieldWidget, here my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text("SQLite Application"),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("Name of Things"),
            TextField()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the result :
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZbzd.png)

Is there a solve to make the TextWidget to aligned to the left ? I've tried to use TextAlign.left on TextWidget but it wont change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

on the `Column`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mainAxisAlignment to Start

```
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

In case you want to place the contents at the Right Side, you can use

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end
```

Comment: i've just tried this but still not working, the TextWidget is still Centered automatically. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
```

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6SLB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
You put your text inside Column widget. Column by default crossAxisAlignment is centre. That's why your text is always on centre.


for example



    Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children:const [
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text("your text....!"),
            TextField()
          ],
        ),



And if you wanna align text without Column, use Align with with alignment.topleft. It will move on left side

    Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text("Name of Things", textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
          ),
```